# Invoke Global Action in Visualforce Page (Lightning)

Tags: visualforce, global-actions

I have a Visualforce Page displayed on a tab in Lightning.  Is there a way to invoke a Global Action from within the Visualforce Page?

I have not looked too much yet, but I think there's a way to invoke a Global Action (or a Quick Action) from within a Lightning Component.  The problem is this page is used by both our Classic setup and Lightning setup so at the moment we're not planning on migrating the Visualforce Page into a Lightning Component.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/units/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_actions_global may be of some use to you!

Comment: @StasChristiansen sorry, no that does not help.  I did read through that before I posted my question.  That link describes how to create a Global Action and display a Visual Force page.  I'm looking for the other way around, I want my Visual Force to show a standard Global Action